# How to implement Text Wrapping within a DataGridTextColumn

Tags: wpf, xaml

First off I am using WPF and DataGrid because I want Column Headers. However I am not married to this solution if there is a way to do this and still have column headers.

Now I have done some extensive searching and tried various solutions that I found via googling but none of these seem to work or are not directly targeted at the issue I am having and further do not seem to be translatable either.

*** I tried the following:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="LeftColumnStyle">
    <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
</Style>

<DataGridTextColumn Header="Comments" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource LeftHeaderStyle}" CellStyle="{StaticResource LeftColumnStyle}" Binding="{Binding Path=Comments, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="250" />
```

*** But the wrapping did not work -- so I tried the following:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Comments" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource LeftHeaderStyle}" Binding="{Binding Path=Comments, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="250" >
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="14"/>
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Width" Value="250"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

*** The column wraps but does not auto-size in height so it simply seems to be truncating

I tried putting a Textblock directly within the DataGridTextColumn and bind the data to the Textblock but the DataGridTextColumn gives an error saying that it does not support direct content.

So in a nutshell I am trying to word wrap the columns that have text that will go beyond the preset cell width (I have more than one of these -- Description and Comments along with 5 other cells that do not wrap because they never exceed the  preset cell width) however I cannot seem to get the height to adjust accordingly.  I am okay with all the columns expanding in height for a row if either/both of the wrapping columns need more height much like that which would happen in an excel spreadsheet but I cannot even get the specific columns to expand when word wrapping.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dang okay found my error -- the second one works I just had the RowHeight set at the DataGrid level -- removed it and it now expands the Height as expected.   So slightly different question -- can the latter be some how done successfully within the former -- aka I would like to do it via a Style but the above Style does not wrap the text.

Comment: The right way to control the text block in `DataGridTextColumn` is via `ElementStyle` like you did. You can take the style in second snippet to resources and `Dynamic/StaticResource` it on each column. It'll amount to same effort as first snippet.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same question earlier today and solved it by the following:

```
<DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
```